# Notify Client from ASP.NET server during long operations

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, comet

I am designing a system where the requirement is as follows:
I have to send a large file (10mb +) to asp.net through AJAX. The file will be sorted in the server and it will take time. I have to notify the client the status of the sorting accurately.Suppose I am sorting 100 sets of data from the file. In this case I have to notify the client after sorting of each set is finished.
How can I do it?
Any suggestion with link to implementation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using SignalR to accomplish this available on NuGet here  http://nuget.org/packages/SignalR and its project page on git hub here https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR . You should be able to find a variety of tutorials on google.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a professional solution, you should try [PokeIn](http://pokeinc.om). It targets each client individually (which is very important in your situation - especially for security reasons)

It helps you to access .NET methods from client side and call them per client (Secure)..

Also... It allows you to benefit from reverse ajax and [websocket](http://www.pokein.com/Help/WebSocketFeature.aspx)s without any server side boundaries. PokeIn websocket feature doesn't require .NET 4.5 or Server 8 etc.